# Error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty file name Android

Tags: android, mysql

I'am creating application which gets data from `MySQL` db. Few days ago I made few big changes one of them is that instead of multiple activity forms,I am using **fragments and toolbar** to switch between them. After that i noticed that i got this error:

```
02/com.example.kurpaest.kurpaest W/JNIHelp﹕ Discarding pending exception (java.lang.NullPointerException) to throw java/lang/IllegalArgumentException
09-12 14:50:53.180  15402-15402/com.example.kurpaest.kurpaest E/MSG﹕ **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty file name**
```

This error shows up when my top 5 places is returning null. But when I try to debug application it runs smoothly with out error or any kind problem.

My server is on my pc and i connect to it using IP address which is provided by ISP.

One more interesting thing is that this error shows up more often when wifi is used instead of mobile network.

One of my guesses is that  servers configuration is incorrect and second part is that all tabs makes there own requests to server instead of one complete request.

**In the doInBackground() method the app  stops suddenly:**

```
 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gps = new GpsTracker(context);
            }
        });

        HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
           //param.put("lat", String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude()));
        // param.put("long", String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude()));
        JSONObject json =  jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products,"GET",param);
        try{
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            switch(success){
                case 1:
                    products =  json.getJSONArray(TAG_LUNCH);
                    for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name =c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                Log.d("MSG", name);
                        String picture ="images/"+c.getString(TAG_PICTURE)+".png";
                Log.d("MSG", picture+"wasd");
                        String cost = c.getString(TAG_COST);
                Log.d("MSG", cost);
                        String lat = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
                        String longi = c.getString(TAG_LONG);
                Log.d("MSG", lat + longi);
                        String worktime = c.getString(TAG_WORKTIME);
                **Log.d("MSG", worktime);**

                        String distance = calcDist(lat, longi);


                        lunchList[i][0] = id;

                        lunchList[i][1] = name;

                        lunchList[i][2] = picture;

                        lunchList[i][3] = cost;

                        lunchList[i][4] = worktime;

                        lunchList[i][5] = distance ;

                        gps.stopUsingGPS();
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            notNetworkDialog.setTitle("Neizdevās izveidot savienojumu!");
                            notNetworkDialog
                                    .setMessage("Neizdevās izveidot savienojumu ar datu serveri, serveris nav pieejams \n" +
                                            "Mēģināt velreiz?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Jā", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            new LoadLunches().execute();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Nē", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            ((Activity)context).finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = notNetworkDialog.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            notNetworkDialog.setTitle("Neizdevās izveidot savienojumu!");
                            notNetworkDialog
                                    .setMessage("Neizdevās izveidot savienojumu ar datu serveri, lūdzu pārliecinaties, ka tālrunis ir savienots ar internetu! \n" +
                                            "Mēģināt velreiz?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Jā", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            new LoadLunches().execute();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Nē", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            ((Activity)context).finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = notNetworkDialog.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 0:
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            notNetworkDialog.setTitle("Kļūda");
                            notNetworkDialog
                                    .setMessage("Kļūme pieprasījuma! \n" +
                                            "Mēģināt velreiz?")
                                    .setCancelable(false)
                                    .setPositiveButton("Jā", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            new LoadLunches().execute();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton("Nē", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            ((Activity)context).finish();
                                        }
                                    });
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = notNetworkDialog.create();
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
    Log.d("MSG",e.toString());

        }

        return null;
    }
```

**Programs works till Log.d("MSG",worktime).**
Then skips calculations and continues at these lines:

```
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   super.onPostExecute(s);
   pDialog.dismiss();
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
     lunchAdapter adapter = new lunchAdapter(getActivity(), lunchList, lunchid);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't  find real cause of such error in my case. Because i recived all data from my DB and further there is no any other files which  name could be wrong or missing. So my workaround was quite simple.

```
   getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
 lunchAdapter adapter = new lunchAdapter(getActivity(), lunchList, lunchid);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
```

i added new lines

```
       getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
if(lunchlist==null){
new LoadLunches().execute();
}else{
     lunchAdapter adapter = new lunchAdapter(getActivity(), lunchList, lunchid);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
```